# nginx rewrite rules with regex applied to one subdirectory only

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url, regex

I've been frustrated for days trying to figure this out, so any advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

I've recently added a section called `/links` to a site at **somehost.com** but can't seem to get the rewrite rules going for this directory (see below). All other paths of the domain are working fine (say for example **somehost.com/browse/video/whatever** redirects to **somehost.com/by/whatever/** fine) and all other rewrite rules seem to still be working great, it's just the newly added `location /links/` section to my conf where things fall apart.

The following conf fails on line 27 -- The error I get when using `service nginx restart` is: *directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";"*  but I can see that the end line terminates with a ; so I'm not sure what's wrong. Perhaps something with the regex?

My nginx conf is below. Any ideas on what to alter to get URLs like **somehost.com/links/page/3** or **somehost.com/links/tag/sometopic/page/2** working?

Thanks!

```
server {
  server_name somehost.com;
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/somehost.com;
  include /etc/nginx/php.conf;

  location / {
    index index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/somehost.com.log;

    #handle old variable redirects first, before dealing with current permalinks
    rewrite ^/?browse/video/(.*) /by/$1 permanent;

    #set a 30-day expires header on static files for cache
    if (-f $request_filename) { expires 30d; break; }    

    #do current permalinks with args
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }

  #handle static redirects from old URLs and rewrite
  location /browse/title { rewrite ^(.*)$ /browse/?orderby=title redirect; }
  location /browse/featured { rewrite ^(.*)$ /by/featured/ permanent; }

  #handle /links permalinks etc
  location /links/ {
    rewrite "tag/(.+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/s/([^/]+)(/)?"$ /?tag=$1&page=$2&s=$3 break;
    rewrite "tag/(.+)/page/([0-9]{1,})(/)?" /?tag=$1&page=$2 break;
    rewrite tag/(.+)/s/([^/]+)(/)? /?tag=$1&s=$2 break;
    rewrite tag/([^/]+)(/)? /?tag=$1 break;
    rewrite rss/([^/]+) /rss.php?tag=$1 break;
    rewrite rss /rss.php break;
    rewrite "page/([0-9]{1,})/s/([^/]+)" /index.php?page=$1&s=$2 break;
    rewrite "page/([0-9]{1,})" /index.php?page=$1 break;
    rewrite go/([0-9]+) /ir.php?id=$1 break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The dollar is outside of the quotes in the first regular expression of your rewrite.

Comment: Of course it answers the question, it's the syntax error that prevents the compilation of the configuration and thus no redirect is working, because nginx is refusing to apply the newly added location block.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misread.